# Can AKV only push EventGrid notification to LA workspace

Tags: azure-keyvault

We have AKV instance which stores lots of secrets. We have enabled diagnostics settings as below to push logs to LogAnalytics workspace and we can see it pushes lots of logs/metrics to workspace.
Is it possible to only push selective metrics? I want to push only logs which are related to Event notification (e.g[image]. secrets expiry etc) so that our LA workspace doesn’t get flooded with unnecessary logs.

Appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: You could use the `Events` blade (from Azure portal) to filter out the logs. Not sure if you can send directly to log analytics tho.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to filter logs by type for log analytics.
You can filter it in log analytics workspace with query.